# Hiding columns in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am newish to css grid and I am trying to figure out how I can make a column completely go away and enforce the others to stack.

I basically want the red crossed out ones below to completely go away and just stack all the others in the grid into several rows.

[image]

With that code below I want `block 4` to disappear. Then I want blocks 1/2/3/5/6 to stack.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(155px, 1fr)) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Block 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Block 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Block 3
  </div>
  <div>
    Block 4
  </div>
  <div>
    Block 5
  </div>
  <div>
    Block 6
  </div>
</div>
```

A codepen of it:

https://codepen.io/allencoded/pen/goNYwv

Comment: Can you use FLEX?

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJgBxG

Comment: Very close to what i am after however I wanted to completely hide block 4 and not have it wrap down.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ensure that there can only be four items per row:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(20%, 1fr));
grid-gap: 10px;
```

With 20% minimum width per item, and a grid gap (of any length), there can never be more than four items per row.

Then, hide the fourth item in each row:

```
div:nth-child(4) { visibility: hidden; }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeKzzx

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(20%, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(4) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Block 1</div>
  <div>Block 2</div>
  <div>Block 3</div>
  <div>Block 4</div>
  <div>Block 5</div>
  <div>Block 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about `.wrapper div {overflow: hidden}` instead of `visibility: hidden`? That could be applied across the board and as the grid cell gets too small the content just disappears. But I may be missing corner cases.

Comment: Apparent source for the above : https://newbedev.com/hiding-columns-in-css-grid

Comment: @JPFotoz - It's the reverse. They copied my answer.

Answer (score -5):

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(155px, 1fr)) 0;
```

One cannot see that which has 0 width.

If you want to see it on hover for example just redefine the grid-template-columns.

```
.wrapper:hover {
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(155px, 1fr)) 1kebab; // 1 kebab being your new width.
}
```

Comment: I can't make this work, neither with `0fr` nor with `0` for the width of the hidden column. Can you provide a sample snippet?